# Implementing User-Defined Function with expression

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, user-defined-functions

Is it possible to implement user-defined function in SQL Server that has parameter expression and return type is same as expression?

Similar to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/nullif-transact-sql.

Basically, I'm looking to implement extended version of NULLIF function.

Comment: You can use `sql_variant`, but otherwise I don't think you can have dynamic typing.

Comment: And `sql_variant` often doesn't really help as you need to cast it to the base type if you want to perform any further operations on  it.

Answer (score 1):

No.

This is a capability that only built in functions have.

The grammar for creating scalar functions requires

```
RETURNS return_data_type
```

Which means you have to pick a specific return data type at design time. You can't have it inferred from the datatype passed in.